# Visa-free countries using US Refugee Travel Document?

Tags: visas, passports, international-travel, refugees

I know there is a lot of topics related to US Refugee Travel Document, but I'm not able to find an exact answer.
 Which countries accept US Refugee Travel Document without a visa? (thankful for the official resource)

there is a lot of resources and each of them a saying different list of countries, basically not able to identify an exact list

Comment: Which official US sources have you already searched? Have you tried contacting US Citizenship & Immigration Services?

Comment: @Traveller US authorities might present information, but from the traveler's perspective it's still second-hand. A more authoritative source would be the individual countries about which the question ("Can I enter visa-free on a Refugee Travel Document?") is asked...some of which, I'm sure, don't have this information easily available online.

Comment: @David Agreed - but just trying to narrow down search options. As it stands, realistically the question is probably too broad to answer. A search of the tag refugees’ on TSE only revealed information about a very limited number of countries.